# I am trying to take intake and display name and password, but nothing happening on submit button?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to take intake no. of user and based on the intake no. want to display name and password.But it just display a text_box and a submit button, and nothing happens.

Code is this :-

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('wp');

if(isset($_POST['t1'])&&isset($_POST['submit'])){
$t1=$_POST['t1'];

$query="SELECT  `name` ,  `password` FROM  `register` WHERE  `intake` ='$t1'";

if($result=mysql_query($query)){
?>
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>password</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $name=$row['name'];
    $password=$row['password'];
    echo"<tr>
    <td>$name</td>
    <td>$password</td>
    </tr>";
    }
}
}

?>
</tbody>
</table>

<form action="table.php" method="post">

<input type="text" name="t1"  />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Thank in advance.

`

Comment: This is because you have rule `if($_POST['t1'] && $_POST['submit'])`. Do love the function `var_dump` to dump $_POST and be sure what goes under the hood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['t1'])&&isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

if you are checking for $_POST['t1'] you dont need to checkfor $_POST['submit']

this might be better for you

```
if(isset($_POST['t1'])&&!empty($_POST['t1'])){
```

Comment: Technically this is a good advice and should be given as answer. However +1 for your nice code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok, where to start.

1. mysql_query is deprecated, use [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [pdo](http://php.net/pdo)
2. If you choose to not listen to #1, then at least [sanitize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) your input before inserting to database.
3. Your submit button is not named 'submit' so your check for $_POST['submit'] wont work.
4. Don't store plaintext passwords. This whole script scares me.

Comment: Yea, I on my way to make password md5 encrypted, about sql injection I am not getting any marks for that in the assignment.And my submit button is not submitted, it make feel like an idiot.The the problem isset($_POST['submit']).Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

The following should be inside the `if(isset(..` clause. As it is, it is outside the clause.

```
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am sure if it is the reason that it does not show, but it is wrong.

Comment: Maybe this isnt the issue cause too much browser supports invalid html too. At least he should see something.